# Returns "System.Collections.Generic.List" instead of recordset in XML or JSON

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

I have a table of employees that I am wanting to return all to the browser in XML. I have followed the tutorial here "http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2016/09/aspnet-web-api-and-sql-server.html" and did this in the same way. However, when I run this I do not get the list in XML at all.

I put this into the browser address bar:
Employee/GetAll

```
{CONTROLLER CODE}
// GET: ALL Employee
public List<DimEmployee> GetAll()
    {
       using (AdventureWorks_MBDEV_DW2008Entities entities = new      AdventureWorks_MBDEV_DW2008Entities())
        {
            return entities.DimEmployees.ToList();
        }
    }
```

I get this returned in the browser window instead of XML or JSON:
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AdventureWorksDataAccess.DimEmployee]

I have seen two tutorials where this returns XML but for some reason not for me. I am using MVC5 Web API; can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Thanks.

Comment: The tutorial you linked uses `IEnumerable<T>` as return type, not `List<T>`. Change your method to have a return type of `IEnumerable<DimEmployee>` and see if that helps

Comment: I tried that and it still returns the same thing, not sure what the next step would be as I have done it pretty much like the tutorial says and also look at other examples. It should be coming back with an XML response.

Comment: Found one issue and fixed it:

    I created a WebApi controller that for some reason was inheriting Controller and not ApiController
    public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    
 
 I fixed that and now I just get an error.
 Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Employee/Get

Comment: You are requesting `Get` but your controller action is named `GetAll`

Comment: I can actually get an individual employee. But now when I go to grab all 200 or so the it just keeps loading and loading and loading with no error but never gets the employees.

     public IEnumerable<DimEmployee> Get()
        {
            using (AdventureWorks_MBDEV_DW2008Entities entities = new AdventureWorks_MBDEV_DW2008Entities())
            {
                entities.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                return entities.DimEmployees.ToList();
            }
        }

Answer (score 3):

you might want to update your function to

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAll()
    {
       using (AdventureWorks_MBDEV_DW2008Entities entities = new AdventureWorks_MBDEV_DW2008Entities())
        {
            return Json(entities.DimEmployees.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

This should take care of the incorrect return value.